# How can I get Safari 4 on OS X to always show the tab bar?

Tags: macos, browser-addons, safari, tabs

I just installed Mac OS X Snow Leopard from scratch on my MacBook.  While I'm generally a fan of Firefox, I'm taking this opportunity to give Safari another honest try.  So, I would like to get Safari configured similar to the way I use Firefox.

One of my annoyances with Safari is the tab bar doesn't always show.  Rather, Safari only shows it when needed.  However, I'm *very* used to double-clicking in the empty area right of existing tabs to open a new tab.  Obviously, when only one page is open, I can't do that. :-(

So, what's the *easiest* way to get the tab bar **always** showing in Safari, i.e. even when only one page is open?  Is there an add-on that makes this a cinch, or do I need to edit hidden configuration files?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Press <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>, or go to View » Show Tab Bar.

Comment: Even easier. I wonder why they don't show this in "Preferences" ! It is, after all, a preference! Anyway, I've confirmed that this does *exactly* the same thing under the covers as @Chealion's solution by verifying the before and after states via "defaults read com.apple.Safari AlwaysShowTabBar". That changed from 0 to 1 and **stays that way** when I set the tab bar to be shown and quit Safari. So this is the easiest solution, I think -- no terminal commands required.

Comment: Completely forgot they moved it there. D'oh.

Answer (score 6):

In Safari 3 the option used to be available in the Tabs section of Safari preferences. In Safari 4 it was moved to the View Menu.

Alternatively you can apply it by running the following command in your Terminal (after quitting Safari):

```
defaults write com.apple.Safari AlwaysShowTabBar -bool YES
```

Comment: +1.  Thanks - works like a charm, and it was simple.  I was afraid I'd have to dig into hidden folders and edit configuration files.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

This might be a stupid solution but you can open more than one tab upon launch of Safari and this way you'll have tab bar.

Comment: Actually, it wouldn't be a terrible idea, but does Safari support opening multiple home pages / tabs when it's launched?

Comment: The closest I can find is in Safari preferences, New windows open with: Choose tabs folder…